# Resources for solving integration problems analytically

Tags: reference-request, integration

I've started dealing with a lot of (many times nasty) integrals in my research.  When there an integral that I can't readily solve using usual methods (like substitution and integration by parts), I try the following sources, in this order:

1. [Gradshtein & Ryzhik 7th ed.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123736374)
2. [Wofram Functions page](http://functions.wolfram.com/)
3. [Handbook of Mathematical Functions](http://www.convertit.com/go/convertit/reference/ams55.asp?Res=150&Page=-1)
4. Google (which is how I found this website)

I am wondering what sources of help do others employ when faced with difficult integration problems that require analytical solution (other than posting here.)

Thank you!

Comment: [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/) would be the updated Abramowitz and Stegun...

Comment: The *Integrals and Series* books by Prudnikov, Brychkov, and Marichev would also be a nice compendium.

Comment: In the good old days before the internet, I used to use the [Handbook of Mathematics](http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Mathematics-I-N-Bronshtein/dp/3540721215/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1315805981&sr=8-1) by Bronshtein (whose name is spelled "Bronstein" in the German version). It contains quite a number of integrals, but I don't know whether any of them go beyond the other resources listed; I haven't used it for a while now.

Comment: @joriki: I haven't checked my copy in a while to see if it has stuff that the others don't, but it's good to add that to Bullmoose's list anyway. :) Well, that and Jahnke-Emde...

Comment: Thanks everyone for helpful suggestions!  And J.M., thanks for the pointer to the DLMF!

Answer (score 2):

[Computer algebra systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) could be of great help here. For example, Mathematica boasts to be able to solve most of indefinite and definite integrals from books like Gradshtein & Ryzhik.

There is also [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Calculus.html), which uses the Mathematica kernel. But the time spent on a problem is strictly limited, so it doesn't work for more or less complicated expressions.

Comment: But note that a. it remains useful to be skeptical of the results a computing environment spits out, and b. computing environments won't necessarily return the most convenient closed form for a given integral.

Comment: J. M. ain't a mathematician:  I've worked with *Mathematica* for decades almost never had problem with b).  One uses `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` or computationally make a substitution.  As for a), we should be even *more* skeptical about hand calculation for very difficult problems!